# java.lang.NullPointerException error in android app

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Please could you help me with the error "java.lang.NullPointerException".
My application crashes in the emulator when I try to start my QuizActivity.java through the "Neues Spiel" Button from the MainActivity.java. (I cleaned the project and tried a different emulators)
I looked for some answers and tried different things but i didn't find my mistake, maybe it is because I am an android-java newbie.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.app_name;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    TextView titel;
    Typeface font_alexbrush;
    long score=0;


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {}
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Context context = this;
        final Button Beenden_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Beenden_btn);
        final Button NeuesSpiel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NeuesSpiel_btn);
        final Button Impressum = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Impressum_btn);

        Typeface font_alexbrush = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Font/alexbrush.ttf");
        TextView titel= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titel);
        titel.setTypeface(font_alexbrush);

        Impressum.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){     
            public void onClick(View x) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Impressum.class);
                    startActivity(intent);}});   

        NeuesSpiel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){    
            public void onClick(View x) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuizActivity.class);

                    startActivity(intent);
                        finish();}});

            Beenden_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){   
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                    alertDialogBuilder  .setMessage("Soll HistoryQuiz beendet werden?")
                                        .setCancelable(false)
                                        .setPositiveButton("Ja",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {    finish();
                                                                                                    System.exit(0);}})
                                        .setNegativeButton("Nein",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {dialog.cancel();}});

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();}});}}
```

LogCat

```
05-17 13:50:22.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3636): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 13:50:22.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     at com.example.app_name.QuizActivity.onCreate(QuizActivity.java:39)
05-17 13:50:22.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-17 13:50:22.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-17 13:50:22.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
05-17 13:50:22.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3636):     ... 11 more
05-17 13:58:15.853: E/OpenGLRenderer(3679): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
05-17 13:58:15.857: E/OpenGLRenderer(3679): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
05-17 13:58:16.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3679): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 13:58:16.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3679): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app_name/com.example.app_name.QuizActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 13:58:16.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3679):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
05-17 13:58:16.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3679):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
05-17 13:58:16.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3679):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-17 13:58:16.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3679):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-17 13:58:16.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3679):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 13:58:16.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3679):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-17 13:58:16.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3679):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-17 13:58:16.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3679):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 13:58:16.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3679):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-17 13:58:16.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3679):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-17 13:58:16.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3679):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-17 13:58:16.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3679):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 13:58:16.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3679): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 13:58:16.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3679):     at com.example.app_name.QuizActivity.onCreate(QuizActivity.java:39)
05-17 13:58:16.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3679):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-17 13:58:16.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3679):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-17 13:58:16.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3679):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
05-17 13:58:16.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3679):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: what is line no 39 in QuizActivity.java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an NPE on the line `frage.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());` as `currentQ` is null in your question.

You will have to initialise `currentQ` before using it. Thus, to solve the error add ,

```
currentQ= new Question();
```

before using it. That is, add the above line,after the line

```
quesList=db.getAllQuestions();
```

Thus, it should be like

```
quesList=db.getAllQuestions();
currentQ= new Question();
```

Comment: Great.. :)..Glad that it helped you..

Comment: But now i have another problem, the question and answer text isn't shown in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently is failing in this line:

```
frage.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
```

This will lead to the conclusion that `frage` or `currentQ` are null references. Based on that you are getting the instance of `frage` in this line:

```
frage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.frage);
```

I will go for `currentQ` as the null reference.

Since you are instantiating this variable based on a condition

```
if(quesList!= null && quesList.size() !=0){
    currentQ=quesList.get(qid);}
}
```

So `questList` is null or empty. You are right, this is a classic noob developer error (not only Android). You must ensure that currentQ variable has a reference before using it or ask for a valid reference and you will be fine

```
if (currentQ != null) {
    frage.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
    a.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
    b.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
    c.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
    d.setText(currentQ.getOPTD());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error (NullPointerException) means you are trying to access a null variable at line 39 of QuizActivity. If I counted right, this would be:

```
frage.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
```

Which means that either frage or currentQ is null at that moment. My guess would be currentQ, but to make sure, you can Log it like this:

```
Log.d("Tag", "Is frage null? " + (frage == null));
Log.d("Tag", "Is currentQ null? " + (currentQ == null));
```

You'll see the results in your logcat (which I'll assume you know how to use since it's off topic).

If you find out frage is null, it means `findViewById(R.id.frage)` returned null. This is the case when the activity can't find a view with the given ID in the layout set in `setContentView()`. So either the ID of the view is wrong or the layout is wrong.

If you find out `currentQ` is null, this means you haven't initiated your object before trying a function on it. In this case, you instantiate `currentQ` on the condition that:

```
quesList!= null && quesList.size() !=0
```

Which means it wasn't the case.

Hope this helps